# Has it been conjectured that all $k$-multiperfect numbers are multiples of $k$?

Tags: number-theory, perfect-numbers

A quick glance at the list of the first  $ k $ -multiperfect numbers for small  $ k $  makes me think that all  $ k $ -multiperfect numbers are multiples of  $ k $ , which is a generalization of the famous "no odd perfect number" conjecture.
Has this conjecture appeared so far ? If yes, what are the results towards it so far ?

Comment: Wikipedia says it's an open question whether $k$-perfect numbers are divisible by $k!$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan:  By chance, do you happen to know of any reference (in the literature) to the conjecture that $k$-perfect numbers must be divisible by $k!$?  I checked the Wikipedia page and there is none there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am writing this answer so that this question does not remain in the unanswered queue.*

---

In a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946432/is-every-multiperfect-number-also-pseudoperfect/4034053#comment8329727_4034053) to [my answer to a closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4034053/28816), [Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82961) asserted that $459818240$ is $3$-perfect, but not divisible by $6$.

[WolframAlpha computational verification that $459818240$ is $3$-perfect](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DivisorSigma%5B1%2C459818240%5D%2F459818240)

[WolframAlpha computational verification that $459818240$ is indivisible by $6$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=459818240%2F6)

---

This settles the open question as to whether all $k$-perfect numbers are divisible by $k!$.