# Is every multiperfect number also pseudoperfect?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

It seems like something that should be pretty obvious but I don't quite get why would it be true. For example, in the case of 2-fold perfect numbers, or simply perfect numbers, it is evident because

$$\sigma(n) - n = n$$

so you just add all the divisors except itself.

We call a positive integer $n>1$ multi-perfect , if $k:=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ is an integer , in the case $k=2$ the number is called perfect.

> What about the multi-perfect numbers that are not perfect (the case $k>2$) ? Are they all pseudoperfect ?

Comment: Pseudoperfect numbers, sometimes also called semiperfect, are numbers for which the sum of all or some of its divisors is the number itself.

Comment: All multiples of $6$ are pseudoperfect, and so far all multiperfect numbers I got with PARI/GP (the perfect numbers excluded) are multiples of $6$. There could however be counterexamples. But at first sight, it seems to be the case.

Comment: $459818240$ is not a multiple of $6$, but it is a multiple of $20$. Such numbers are pseudoperfect as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: I do not understand why this question was downvoted.

Comment: I checked *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory* by Richard K. Guy and your inquiry does not seem to be covered there, @aaac991.  I would suggest that you next check the *Handbook of Number Theory*, Volumes 1 and 2.

Comment: FWIW, the multiperfect numbers are tabulated [here](http://oeis.org/A007691).

Comment: The multi-perfect numbers in the above OEIS-link that correspond with $k>2$ , are all divisible by $6$ or by $20$ , hence are pseudoperfect. If we can trust this entry, all multi-perfect numbers upto $10^{300}$ are pseudoperfect.

Answer (score 0):

Here I consider the case of $k$-perfect numbers where $k \geq 3$. (The case $k=2$ was considered in the OP.)

It has been conjectured that $k$-perfect numbers ought to be divisible by $k!$.  From Peter's comment, this then implies that $k$-perfect numbers are also pseudoperfect. (Note that the conjecture mentioned also implies that there are no odd $k$-perfect numbers for $k \geq 2$.)

**Update:** As correctly pointed out by Peter, $459818240$ is $3$-perfect but not divisible by $6$.  It is however, divisible by $20$, which still makes it pseudoperfect, as had already been pointed by Peter in a comment underneath the OP.

Comment: $459818240$ is $3$-perfect, but not divisible by $6$.